# Simplify and Speed up incredibly slow SQL Server query (returning one row for an item)

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query that is incredibly slow (from the full outer join?).  I would like to speed this up, but I'm at a loss.

I have an `Item` table and a `UPC` table (with two columns, `Code` and `UPC`).  The `UPC` table just links UPC's to codes for this query. I need it to ONLY return one row as sometimes there are multiple UPC's that point to the same code.

The query I ran before this was quite fast, however if an `Item` wasn't in the `UPC` table, it would never show up in the query results despite being in the `Item` table.

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    UPC.UPC, Item.Name, Item.Code, Item.Retail, 
    Item.LBDRetail, Item.ClassID 
FROM 
    Item 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    UPC ON Item.Code = UPC.Code 
WHERE 
    Item.Code = (SELECT TOP(1) Code 
                 FROM UPC 
                 WHERE UPC = '99999' OR Code='99999') 
    OR Item.Code = '99999'
```

Comment: why do you need full outer join here ?

Comment: Using a `WHERE` in  table involved in an outer join will exlude many rows because they are NULL

Comment: Makes no sense to me.   Top 1 without an order by is nondeterministic.  The use use of item.code in the where kills the outer join.

Comment: What did you add to the query so that it began to perform slowly? What was it like before?

Comment: SELECT UPC.UPC, Item.Name, Item.Code, Item.Retail, Item.LBDRetail, Item.ClassID FROM Item full outer JOIN UPC ON Item.Code = UPC.Code WHERE Item.Code=(SELECT TOP(1) Code FROM UPC WHERE UPC = '99999' OR Code= '99999'

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your `WHERE` statement like so: `WHERE Item.Code IN ('99999', (SELECT TOP(1) Code FROM UPC WHERE UPC = '99999' OR Code='99999') )`?

Comment: I tried that, but It's still just as slow.  It took 4 seconds to run with that change.

Comment: I can't tell from the question whether `Code` is the primary key on `Item` or `UPC` (or neither) but do you have an index on that column on the table(s) which it is not the primary key for?

Comment: The primary key is on UPC in the UPC table and Code in the ITEM table.

Comment: Thanks. Based on that information, my previous question translates as: "do you have an index on Code on the UPC table?" If not, adding one could help the performance.

Comment: That makes sense.  I don’t currently have an index on that but will add and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining with an `OR` predicate or having it in a `WHERE` predicate slows the query down and what usually helps (sometimes tremendously) is rewriting the query with `UNION (ALL)` so why don't you try the following:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    UPC.UPC, Item.Name, Item.Code, Item.Retail, 
    Item.LBDRetail, Item.ClassID 
FROM 
    Item 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    UPC ON Item.Code = UPC.Code 
WHERE 
    Item.Code = (SELECT TOP(1) Code 
                 FROM UPC 
                 WHERE UPC = '99999' OR Code='99999') 
UNION
SELECT TOP(1) 
    UPC.UPC, Item.Name, Item.Code, Item.Retail, 
    Item.LBDRetail, Item.ClassID 
FROM 
    Item 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    UPC ON Item.Code = UPC.Code 
WHERE Item.Code = '99999'
```

What I'd like to point out is you need to think about your data and whether in your data in particular you can get two different rows by querying with this logic (and for some reason you want one). If you can, then this should be wrapped in a `CTE` preferably (or in a subquery) and then you'd just pretty much do a `SELECT TOP(1) UPC, Name, Code, Retail, LBDRetail, ClassID FROM CTE` query.

Comment: That makes a LOT of sense now.  Thank you for explaining it!